# pynput Keyboard Listener returns shift when shift is pressed, but does not modify shift_pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard-events

I've got a simple program to familiarize myself with Keyboard Listeners using pynput. What it does is not important. What is important is that the `shift_pressed` attribute never seems to change to `True`. My program currently looks like this:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Listener

boo = True
keyboard = Controller()

fib_lst = [0, 1]


def on_press(key):
    print(key)
    print(keyboard.shift_pressed)


Listener(on_press=on_press).start()

while boo:
    nxt = fib_lst[-1] + fib_lst[-2]
    input(nxt)
    fib_lst.append(nxt)
```

I'm trying to do something like this in `on_press` (or `on_release`):

```
def on_press(key):
    if key == Key.delete:
        if keyboard.shift_pressed:
            func1()

        else:
            func2()
```

This code should perform `func1` when shift is pressed or `func2` if it is not. But it is currently only doing `func2` since `shift_pressed` is perpetually false. What can I do differently to get `shift_pressed` to work as it should?

Edit 1: Specified the desired end result more clearly.

Edit 2: Changed the appending string to two different functions to add more clarity.

Edit 3: Changed the parameters of the final question to match the more recent example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the *pynput 1.3.5* documentation.

The various modifier state properties ([`alt_pressed`](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/blob/v1.3.5/lib/pynput/keyboard/_base.py#L477), `alt_gr_pressed`, `ctrl_pressed` and `shift_pressed`) reflect only the state of the [`Controller`](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/blob/v1.3.5/lib/pynput/keyboard/_base.py#L285) instance; it maintains an inner modifier state which is applied when various keys are pressed---for example to uppercase characters from scripts that support it.

This state is separate from the current operating system state and will only change when you send key presses using that specific controller.

There is no general *pynput* method to retrieve the current global modifier state.

Comment: After posting the issue to your github repo, I saw [this closed issue](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/20). I will use the pattern you used in that one for my purposes here. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not hundred percent sure but when I have worked with pynput I noticed that I can handle action on key release, not key press so you can try something like below:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.shift: # handles if key press is shift
        print('foo', end='')

def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.shift:
        print()
    elif key == keyboard.Key.delete:
        print('bar')
    elif key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False

def get_current_key_input():
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()

get_current_key_input()
```

if you need any other help let me know with your specific motive.

Comment: It's detecting the press of Shift just fine. It'll perform an action if I put `if key == Key.shift: do_something` the issue is that it's not changing the shift_pressed attribute, which I'm trying to use so that I can modify the actions of other keys.

Comment: @Eric check now. do you want something like that? you can match character with string `if key.char == 'A':` and perform your desired action.

Comment: I'll modify my question to clarify a little.

Comment: @Eric I have changed answer according to question description modified by you.

Comment: I attempted to clarify again. Thank you for your continued patience and assistance.

Comment: It's working when you hold shift key and press and release delete than it prints foobar

Comment: My question isn't quite so low level. The question is "what can I do to get shift_pressed to work as it should?" The more recent example of using two different functions is a more accurate representation of what I am asking.

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146275/discussion-between-eric-ed-lohmar-and-gahan).